# Creating unique result document names in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, filesystems, timing

I am processing a large document that contains formulas in XML format (the FORMEX standard defined and used by the EU). To render the FORMULA elements, I convert them to SVGs using an XSLT pre-processing step. To generate unique names for the SVG files I take the document name and add an index to it, using the doc-available() function to determine whether the name is already taken.
This strategy has worked well, so I am using the same approach to create very small SVG files that contain an accolade symbol (as these need to be scaled to the size of the table cells and rows). But even when using the exact same method to determine whether a file already exists, my XSLT runs into problems, apparently because the process of creating a file takes too long for the next doc-available() call to register that a new file is present.

My question is: can this be a timing issue? Is it related to the XSL processor (Saxon PE 9.8.0.12) or some file system function (Windows 10)? When I re-run the same code with only one cell that requires an accolade, subsequent runs do give different file names.

The code to determine whether a file already exists is this:

```
    <xsl:template name="setfilename">
    <xsl:param name="number" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
    <xsl:variable name="svgfile" select="concat($basepath,$prefix,$number,'.svg')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="doc-available($svgfile)">
            <xsl:call-template name="setfilename">
                <xsl:with-param name="number" as="xs:integer" select="$number + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$prefix"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$svgfile"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

basepath is the full path of the input XML file without the .xml extension
prefix is a fixed string '-acc-' to differentiate from the generated formulas
number is set to 1 when this template is called from the main code

Comment: I don't think you should expect a sequential execution and any security that `doc-available` finds `xsl:result-document`s created in the same run of a stylesheet. Either pipeline your XSLT with e.g. XProc or other host languages or change your strategy to use `xsl:number` or `generate-id` or accumulators to find unique identifies. Within a single XSLT 3 I think `xsl:iterate` is supposed to ensure "sequential" processing but I doubt that ensures that `doc-available` finds a result-document created in a previous iteration.

Comment: xsl:iterate means that the processing of item N can set parameters for the processing of item N+!, so it creates a functional dependency, which is almost certain to lead to predictable order of execution unless the optimizer is extremely smart. But the language spec is designed to try and stop you doing this kind of thing; work with it rather than against it.

Comment: Why don't you create all filenames **beforehand** and pass these as parameters to the processing? Alternatively, iterative processing can be  achieved if tail-recursive calls are used -- however do check which tail-recursive calls are recognized as such by Saxon, and which aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - it is clear that I cannot count on the doc-available within a single processing run. Creating a pipeline and using an xml:iterate would cause a lot of extra work, too. I found a solution that does not require the XSL to set the file names (as the result of the XSLT will have to be handled by another program, anyway). At least I know I have not overlooked something.